# Python call a member function or variable of an object that is in a list of objects

Tags: python, list, function, object, member

I have a list of objects. I want to call the variables or functions of the objects in that list. (With so many basic keywords in this problem, it's been quite difficult to find a solution or guide for this!)

E.g.:

```
for each in current_staff_list:
   print(current_staff_list[each].variable_name)
```

What's the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each` is already the right element:

```
for each in current_staff_list:
   print(each.variable_name)
```

Python `for` loops give you the element *itself*, not an index into the sequence.